# What are the best practices when specifying package generators in case of a multi-platform package?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I do have a multi-platform package. What are the best practices for preparing packages on different platforms, excluding the foreign packages, using the same CMakeLists.txt file?

(protecting ALL platform specific options, and segregating `set(CPACK_GENERATOR "PACK")` instructions?)

Comment: Please, be specific. Currently the question is formulating so you need a book about CPack, which is "too broad" for being answering on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Say, I do not want to produce .tgz on Linude debian, but I do want it on MAC.

Comment: Generator is (normally) specified in command line. If you won't run `cpack -G TGZ`, then you don't obtain `.tgz`. So, what is a problem?

Comment: I am using `set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")` or maybe `set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB TGZ")`

Comment: So you want to form generators list *conditionally*, dependent from OS you being run, don't you? If so, CMake has variables like *UNIX*, *OSX*, which describe the platorm. Using `if` command with these variables, like in [that randomly choosen script](https://github.com/percolator/percolator/blob/master/CPack.txt), you will achive what you want.

Comment: I am using a CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: You may use exactly same commands in your `CMakeLists.txt` directly. Or  use `include()` for include script with these commands.

Comment: You are right. All the suggested ideas, however, presume that either some manual intervention is needed on different platforms or some `if()` construction should be used. What I wanted to ask, if there is some "best practices" method for the latter.

Comment: There is **no well-defined division** on native/foreigh package types on every platform. So neither CMake nor CPack cannot *automatically* select packages types for you. So you need to select "native" package types manually. And a way of doing this is completely up to you.